# How Do i maintain Scrollview subitem height with Swiftui

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I am new to swift and I am trying to wrap my view in Scrollview. The issue is that, when I wrap the content in the scrollview, the contents shrink. I have the images below.
[image: View without Scrollview]

[image: View with Scrollview]

sample code:

```
 ScrollView(.vertical) {
        GeometryReader { metrics in
            HStack{
                Button(action:{
                    isVisible = true
                }, label: {
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10){
                        Image(systemName: "book.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 28, height: 22)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 15, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                            .foregroundColor(CustomColor.primaryColor)
                            
                        
                        Text("Daily Reading")
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 15, trailing: 0))
                            .foregroundColor(CustomColor.primaryColor)
                    }.frame(maxWidth: metrics.size.width/2.3, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                        .fill(Color.white)
                                        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 2))
                })
                
            Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    
                }, label: {
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10){
                        Image("church")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(maxWidth: 28, maxHeight: 22)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 15, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                            .foregroundColor(CustomColor.primaryColor)
                        
                        Text("Church Prayers")
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 15, trailing: 0))
                            .foregroundColor(CustomColor.primaryColor)
                    }.frame(maxWidth: metrics.size.width/2.3, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                        .fill(Color.white)
                                        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 2))
                })
                
            }.frame(maxHeight: metrics.size.width/2)
            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
        .padding(.vertical, 7.5)
        }
    }
```

I have tried removing the GeometryReader but I am still getting the same result and I can't seem to find any helpful solution online. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the `HStack{...}`, try replacing `.frame(maxHeight: metrics.size.width/2)` with `.frame(height: metrics.size.width/2)`